# Cloudfront Won't Set Expiration Header from S3 Origin

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, content-expiration

I am using an S3 bucket to store a bunch of product images for a large web site. These images are being served through Cloudfront with the S3 bucket as the origin. I have noticed that Cloudfront does not put an expiration header on the image even though I have set the distribution behavior to customize the cache headers and set a long min, max, and default TTL in Cloudfront.

I understand that I can put an expiration on the S3 object, however this is going to be quite impractical as I have millions of images. I was hoping that cloudfront would do me the honors of adding this header for me, but it does not.

So my question is the only way to get this expiration header to apply it every S3 object, or perhaps I am missing something in Cloudfront that will do it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFront's TTL configuration only controls the amount of time *CloudFront* keeps the object in the cache.

It doesn't add any headers.

So, yes, you'll need to set these on the objects in S3.

Note that `Cache-Control:` is usually considered a better choice than `Expires:`.

---

A alternative to avoid updating the onjects is to configure a proxy server in EC2 in the same region as the bucket, and let the server add the headers as the responses pass through it.

```
Request:  CloudFront >> Proxy >> S3
Response: S3 >> Proxy >> CloudFront
```

...for what it's worth.

Comment: Thank you. I am running a script to update them all. I'll keep the proxy idea in my toolbox though.